# Using JavaScript-Iterables with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, collections, underscore.js, ecmascript-6, iterable

I'd like to use JS6' new [Set-object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in conjunction with [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/). As far as I know JavaScript supports a concept called ``Iterators and generators''. The following code does not work...

```
var omega = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
var filtered = _.(omega).filter(even); // filtered should be of type set
```

...and my workaround looks like this...

```
var omega = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
var filtered = new Set(_.([...omega]).filter(even));
```

Are iterable objects supported by underscore? If not, what would be the most elegant way to avoid typing [...myIterable] and keep the set datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore does not yet support ES6 iterables. https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/2147

Underscore need to be able to understand what you are passing it, so your workaround to convert the iterable to an array first seems like the best approach.